# How to perform update and insert in one query for multiple IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Once upon a time I needed to perform a complex modification (update of all rows with a foreign key given and insert a new row with the same foreign key and some new values) for all foreign key values returned by select from a table where these values are primary keys.

It was a "do it once" scenario, not for coding.

So, I made the following script: declared a stored procedure with update and insert, declared a fast forward cursor over the select, then executed the procedure for each Ids fetched, and at last dropped the procedure.
However, I'm almost sure there's more optimal way.

What will you recommend in case such scenario will occur again?

P.S. MS SQL Server 2005.

P.P.S. Update and select were in such relations that a row, satisfying the select conditions, after its update doesn't satisfy those condition anymore.

UPD:

For example:

Table UserLog, that is to be modified (actual column names and values are obfuscated):

[…, user_Id: 25, date: 01.01.1654, check_life_signs: 0],

[…, user_Id: 47, date: 05.05.1717, check_life_signs: 0],

[…, user_Id: 25, date: 01.01.998, check_life_signs: 1],

[…, user_Id: 54, date: 10.12.2019, check_life_signs: 0],

…

Need to:

```
1. Select distinct Id from User join UserLog on User.Id = UserLog.user_Id 
where User.IsVampire = 1 and UserLog.check_life_signs = 0 and UserLog.date < 
(some date given)
2. For all such Id: UPDATE UserLog Set check_life_signs = 1; INSERT INTO 
UserLog (user_Id, date, check_life_signs) VALUES (id found), GETDATE(), 0
```

So, after the procedure, in case user_Id = 54 is not a vampire, the table UserLog is to become:

[…, user_Id: 25, date: 01.01.1654, check_life_signs: 1],

[…, user_Id: 47, date: 05.05.1717, check_life_signs: 1],

[…, user_Id: 25, date: 01.01.998, check_life_signs: 1],

[…, user_Id: 54, date: 10.12.2019, check_life_signs: 0],

[…, user_Id: 25, date: 12.10.2019, check_life_signs: 0],

[…, user_Id: 47, date: 12.10.2019, check_life_signs: 0],

…

Comment: Post sample data with the expected output, also what you have tried so far,

Comment: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/ you can check this merge into

Comment: post sample data

Answer (score 1):

Try below query to get the expected result -

***Step 1 - Select & Stored ID in the temp table which needs to use to update & insert User log Table***

```
select * into #tempUser
from
(Select distinct id 
   from [User] inner join UserLog on [User].Id = UserLog.user_Id 
   where [User].IsVampire = 1 
   and UserLog.check_life_signs = 0 
   and UserLog.date < getdate()
 )tbl
```

***Step 2 - Update the UserLog table***

```
Update UserLog
Set check_life_signs = 1
From UserLog ul inner join #tempUser on ul.user_Id = #tempUser.Id;
```

***Step 3 - Insert Into the UserLog table***

```
INSERT INTO UserLog 
(user_Id, date, check_life_signs) 
Select id, GETDATE(), 0 from #tempUser;
```

***Step 4 - Drop the Temp table***

```
Drop table #tempUser
```